# How to migrate or import mysql database in sqlserver on Telerik ORM

Tags: telerik

How to add mysql database in Telerik ORM and I wish to convert mysql to sqlserver, Is it possible to have mysql to sqlserver in Telerik

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify your question?  Are you asking to use MySQL with Telerik OpenAccess ORM?

Do you want to use OpenAccess to migrate data from MySQL to SqlServer?  You could use Sql Server Integration Services (SSIS) to perform this operation for you.